# Is there a way to insert a timestamp in a file in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, shell, timestamp

I often find myself needing to type out a timestamp into a text file. Is there a way to quickly insert the current timestamp into a file in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `date` command.

```
date >> my_file.txt
```

Where `my_file.txt` is the file to put the timestamp into.

Look at the manual page for `strftime(3)` (`man 3 strftime`) to see some date formatters you can use. For instance:

```
date +%l:%M >> my_file.txt
```

Will output something like `9:37` (Hour:Minute) to the text file.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command at your shell prompt (or within your shell script):

- date >> /var/log/my_log_file.log

Answer (score 0):

Install xclip:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

And run the following in a command prompt:

```
date +"%Y-%M-%d %H:%M" | while read line; do echo -n "$line"; done | xclip -i -selection clipboard
```

Then you can paste the datetime stamp via ctrl+v into whatever program you choose. You can put the command in a shell script and run it from a keyboard shortcut for convenience.

Comment: Why is this any easier than the solutions we gave? It seems like our solutions are much better, and faster, than this.

Comment: This is more flexible since you can insert the current time into any position of the file from the clipboard. This way I'm not limited to having to append the time to the end of the file. Your solutions are indeed easier and faster if you are content with the limits of appending via command line as opposed to insertion via keyboard shortcut. Insert was a keyword for me.

Comment: I don't understand why the down vote. There are many ways to get to Detroit, and sometimes some roads are closed. So long as it is a correct and functional answer that doesn't duplicate others, it is a valuable addition.